# Raycaster with Three.js and whitestormJS

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, raycasting

I'm having an issue with Raycasting with Three.js and WhitestormJS.
Maybe I didn't understood well some of the underlying principle of this particular element.

What I'm trying to do is syncing the direction of the raycaster with my camera.
So, once it intersect an element, this element will be added to the intersect array.

**The problem is that my "intersect" array stay empty even if I move my camera in the direction of an element.**

On codepen : https://codepen.io/paulbonneau/pen/zdVeJx?editors=1111

My code :

```
const app = new WHS.App([
  new WHS.ElementModule({
    container: document.getElementById('app')
  }),
  new WHS.SceneModule(),
  new WHS.DefineModule('camera', new WHS.PerspectiveCamera({
    position: new THREE.Vector3(0, 6, 18),
    far: 10000
  })),
  new WHS.CameraModule({
    position: {
      y: 2,
      z: 2,
      x: 1,
    },

  }),
  new WHS.RenderingModule({
    bgColor: 0x162129,

    renderer: {
      antialias: true,
      shadowmap: {
        type: THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap
      }
    }
  }, {shadow: true}),
  new WHS.OrbitControlsModule(


    ),
  new WHS.ResizeModule()
]);

app.modules[5].controls.enableZoom = false
var camera = app.get('camera');
crosshair = new THREE.Vector2(0,0);
// Rendu de la skybox càd l'environnement dans lequel se déroule le jeu
var path = "img/skybox/";
var format = '.jpg';
var urls = [

    './skybox/EH_0.front.jpg',
    './skybox/EH_0.back.jpg' ,
    './skybox/EH_0.top.jpg',
    './skybox/EH_0.bottom.jpg',
    './skybox/EH_0.left.jpg',   
    './skybox/EH_0.right.jpg',
];
var reflectionCube = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube(urls, null);
reflectionCube.format = THREE.RGBFormat;
var shader = THREE.ShaderLib[ "cube" ];
shader.uniforms[ "tCube" ].value = reflectionCube;
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
    fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader,
    vertexShader: shader.vertexShader,
    uniforms: shader.uniforms,
    depthWrite: false,
    side: THREE.BackSide
});
//End test

const world = new WHS.Box({ // Create box to contain the 3D space where the game happen
  geometry: {
     width: 100,
     height: 100,
     depth: 100
   },
  material: material
});


world.addTo(app);


var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, envMap: reflectionCube } );

var points = [];
for ( var deg = 0; deg <= 180; deg += 6 ) {

    var rad = Math.PI * deg / 180;
    var point = new THREE.Vector2( ( 0.72 + .08 * Math.cos( rad ) ) * Math.sin( rad ), - Math.cos( rad ) ); // the "egg equation"
    //console.log( point ); // x-coord should be greater than zero to avoid degenerate triangles; it is not in this formula.
    points.push( point );

}
const sphere = new WHS.Sphere({
    geometry: {
      radius: 100
    },

    material: new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0xffffff
    }),

    position: {
      y: 1,
      x: 1,
      z: 0

    }
});




for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

    egg_size = Math.random() * 10-2;
    egg = new WHS.Lathe({
                geometry: {
                    points: points 
                },
                material: material,
                position: {
                    y:  Math.random() * 100 - 50,
                    x: Math.random() * 100 - 50 ,
                    z:  Math.random() * 100 - 50
                },
                rotation: {
                    x: Math.random() * Math.PI/2,
                    y: Math.random() * Math.PI/2,
                    z: Math.random() * Math.PI/2
                },
                scale:{
                    x :  egg_size,
                    z :  egg_size,
                    y :  egg_size
                }
              });
    egg.addTo(sphere);
}

sphere.addTo(world);

raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera, camera.position);
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( app.children );


new WHS.Loop(() => {
    raycaster.setFromCamera( camera.position , camera );

    sphere.rotation.x += 0.01;
    sphere.rotation.y += 0.01;
    for (var i = 0; i < sphere.children.length-1; i++) {
        sphere.children[i].rotation.x += 0.05;
        sphere.children[i].rotation.y += 0.05;
        sphere.children[i].rotation.z += 0.05;
    }
}).start(app);


// Start the app
app.start();
```

Comment: So, what's the problem? Console errors? Unexpected results?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my message.

Answer (score 0):

You're constructing the `raycaster` in the wrong way (as of r87).

```
raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera, camera.position);
```

As shown in the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Raycaster), the `raycaster` is constructed like so:

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
```

The rest of the code looks correct, so I assume that is the problem.

Here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/juanferrer/pen/NvBqpz)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I modified my code according to it but counld not get the result I want. I made a Pen that you can see here if you want to take a look : https://codepen.io/paulbonneau/pen/zdVeJx?editors=1111

Comment: If you read the console, there's an error saying "Unsupported camera type".

Comment: I saw, I tried every type of camera and getting each time the same error message

Comment: You should check with Whitetorm.js (maybe add the tag or something). Doesn't seem to be a problem with THREE.js.

Comment: I resolved the problem with the type of the camera but still have one when i try to add : 
  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( world.children );
In my loop. It return "a.raycast is not a function" in my console.
Any idea about that ?